# Why can an object initialized with A{8} not be passed as an argument?

Tags: c++, types, c++11, initialization, initializer-list

The following code was compiled with VC++ Nov 2012 CTP.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    A(int n)
    {
        cout << n << endl;
    }
};

void f(A)
{}

int main()
{
    A {8}; // OK. A::A(8); is called;

    cout << typeid(decltype(A {8})).name() << endl; // Output 'struct A'

    f(A {8}); // error C2275: 'A' : illegal use of this type as an expression    
}
```

Q1: Why is f(A {8}); not legal?

Q2: Why is A {8} not treated as an instance of A?

**Update:**

**This issue seems a bug of VC++ Nov 2012 CTP.**

Comment: Works fine - http://ideone.com/RE7o0r http://liveworkspace.org/code/4fx7eJ$0

Comment: It seems a bug of VC++.

Comment: The code is legal C++11.

Comment: Does VS2012 support this already?

Comment: I believe the Nov CTP is supposed to support the uniform initialization syntax. @billz

Comment: @bames53, my compiler is just VC++ 2012 Nov CTP.

Comment: @xmllmx, file a bug to connect, please. Since it is still CTP only it contains many bugs. You can use just f({8}) until it is fixed, which is preferable syntax.

Comment: @ixSci, f({8}); is OK with VC++ Nov 2012 CTP.

Comment: They definitely has a bug in the parser, because f((A{8})); works well

Comment: @ixSci, I have submitted a bug to Microsoft. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/779387/vc-nov-2012-ctp-doesnt-support-certain-uniform-initialization-syntax

Answer (score 0):

A {8} is a declaration with an extended initializer list. You cannot use extended initializer lists before C++11. But you can just call the constructor instead.

With C++11 your code is correct.